# Jquery dont allow button to be pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

If i have a button pressed method like this:

```
$('#next').click(function () {
});
```

How can i stop this method being initiated whilst its running. Say the method takes 5 seconds to run and someone clicks it 3 seconds in it breaks so i want to make the div thats being clicked unclickable while the methods running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the clicked link with `<p>loading...</p>`

Comment: Not sure why this only has two upvotes - really if you have something that takes a long time - you should be telling the user you're doing something.  Simply ignoring the users input does not make for a good user experience in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#next').click(function () { 
   $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
   stuffff
   $(this).attr("disabled", ""); 
});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it makes a difference, but you could try $(this).attr("disabled", true);  
$(this).attr("disabled", false);

Comment: Ive being trying to use disabled but its not working.'#next' is a div, not a button. Is this the reason why its not working?

Comment: <div id="clickDiv" style=" background-color:Green"><br /><br /></div>
$("#clickDiv").click(function () { $(this).attr("disabled",true); alert("here"); });

This works for me - it alerts the message once, but is disabled after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "disabled" to disable the button while your execution, as like byron said